# Sliders in a C# WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, slider

I just want to create a slider in my C# WPF project and write the value of the slider into a label. I know this is probably really easy to do but I can't manage to get it working. So here is my slider in my XAML code:

```xml
<Slider Height="21" Minimum="-255" Maximum="255" x:Name="sld_brightness" />
<Label x:Name="lb_brightness_nb" />
```

Now, I try to change the value of the label according to the slider value in my C# code:

```cs
public void sld_brightness_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    lb_brightness_nb.Content = (int)sld_brightness.Value;
}
```

This code does compile but doesn't do anything. It is not working. What's wrong?

Comment: where is lb_brightnessValue defined? Are you looking for lb_brightness_nb ?

Comment: Oops, ya, I edited my post accordingly. Still, even with a checkpoint onto that line, it just doesn't seem to execute it at all. It doesn't trigger.

Comment: Sorry, you need to add the eventhandler too on your xaml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could bind it directly; there's no need to create an event handler for this.

```
<Slider Height="21" Minimum="-255" Maximum="255" x:Name="sld_brightness" />
<Label x:Name="lb_brightness_nb"
    Content="{Binding ElementName=sld_brightness,Path=Value,Converter={StaticResource DoubleToStringConverter}}" />
```

---

If you want to use the event handler, then it looks like you're missing the wireup:

```
<Slider Height="21" Minimum="-255" Maximum="255" x:Name="sld_brightness"
    ValueChanged="sld_brightness_ValueChanged" />
```

**Edit**

To show only the integer, use an `IValueConverter`.  Add it to the resources section using `<local:DoubleToStringConverter x:Key="DoubleToStringConverter" />`.

```
public class DoubleToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Math.Round((double)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is working like a breeze. Any way to only get integers as values of the slider?

Comment: Which means in the end that I will have to use an event endler?

Comment: @dnLL no, you still don't need an event handler.  See my update above.

Comment: It works pretty well with the event handler. Sounds like I was only missing the ValueChanged property of my slider. Thank you very much, I didn't even know that I could bind directly a value into my XAML code.

Comment: Is there any advantage of not using an event handler?

Comment: @dnLL the problem with event handlers is that using them too much can hurt performance.  Also they tend to create tightly-coupled code (in other words, they're not MVVM friendly).  In general I think binding is a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the name of the label is lb_brightness_nb then lb_brightnessValue. 
You can change the name of it to compile.

Your code should look like :

```
public void sld_brightness_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    lb_brightness_nb.Content = sld_brightness.Value;
}
```

- you dont need to convert the Value to int as well.

Let me know if that is what you are talking or something else.